# GRUB does not boot automatically

Tags: linux, boot, grub

GRUB does not boot my kernel automatically or display a boot menu. Why not?

My /boot/grub/grub.conf contains the following

```
default 0
timeout 5

root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/3.8.13
```

Instead of booting, I'm given a prompt, I can then do:

```
> kernel /boot/3.8.13
> boot
```

and the kernel will start. I want this to happen automatically.

I should probably mention that the kernel *fails* to boot, but that is a different topic and I don't see how it could be related (I'm assuming GRUB has no way of knowing this, unless it would be something trivial like an incompatible architecture, however it is not that trivial).

I *have* followed the guide at http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/grub-error-guide.xml section 11. "Grub Just Shows a Grub Prompt"

In particular I have verified that the file grub.conf exists under /boot/grub and that the menu.lst in the same directory is a symbolic link to grub.conf. I have also executed the grub-install command.

I have tried the following arguments to grub-install:

```
grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sda
grub-install --root-directory=/boot /dev/sda
```

My system has one physical HDD, /dev/sda. I have /boot on /dev/sda1 and root on /dev/sda2, which is encrypted. However I'm not even trying to make grub load some initrd yet, first things first I want GRUB to at least be able to start the kernel before I try with the initrd.

Comment: initrd is used by the boot process in conjunction with the kernel so that a temporary `early user space` can be set up to handle loading kernel modules needed to load, say, soft raid kernel modules. It's possible that grub is considering the lack of an initrd line to be an error.

Comment: I doubt it, because the exact same thing happens when I have an initrd included in my grub.conf. This is also a valid initrd, it makes the boot process proceed further than it otherwise would, just not boot completely.

Answer (score 1):

The config shouldn't be too complicated. I've changed the `root=` to where the root will eventually come from (your encrypted drive). Boot being on a separate partition is part of the problem here.

So lets put things together with how they should end up. First, the real root will be mounted as `/dev/sda2` once you can decrypt it. `/dev/sda2/boot` will be an empty directory where you would mount your boot partition, `/dev/sda1`.

Since `/dev/sda1` is going to be your boot partition, it should not have a boot directory itself, otherwise once it gets mounted, you'll have `/boot/boot/[grub/, 3.8.13, initrd.img, etc]`.

The mount table *would* look something like this:

- `/dev/sda2       /`
- `/dev/sda1       /boot`

Move your kernel to `/dev/sda1/3.8.13`, move your initrd.img to `/dev/sda1/initrd.img`, move your grub directory to `/dev/sda1/grub`.

Next, we want to install grub to the mbr of `/dev/sda`, and never the partition `/dev/sda1`, so our install would look something like `grub-install /dev/sda`. We need to tell it where to find the config files to write to the grub config tables, which is where `--boot-directory` should come in.

Lets assume that while you're in your live cd, fixing this thing, that you've got `/dev/sda1` mounted as `/boot`, and your grub configs are in `/boot/grub`. Install would be `grub-install --boot-directory=/boot /dev/sda`.

If you had `/dev/sda1` mounted as `/mnt/fixboot` while in the livecd, then the config wouldn't change and the install command would change to `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/fixboot`.

Config:

```
default 0
timeout 5

root (hd0,0)
kernel /3.8.13 root=/dev/sda2
initrd /initrd.img
```

The config may change once you figure out how to actually decrypt `/dev/sda2`; it'll probably end up having to be a `/dev/mapper` device.

Comment: Tried this just now, I get: "Error 15" when GRUB loads. No prompt, nothing.

Comment: So I think we're getting confused about what path is what, when we're talking about booting the drive, and talking about modifying the drive from what I assume is a livecd since the drive itself doesn't boot.

Comment: I'm sorry but this makes no sense to me, move the kernel to my encrypted device (/dev/sda2)? How is GRUB even going to be able to read the kernel? Obviously the kernel must reside on the non-encrypted /boot partition (/dev/sda1). When I'm working with this I have mounted /dev/sda2 as /mnt/gentoo and /dev/sda1 as /mnt/gentoo/boot and I've chrooted to /mnt/gentoo.

Comment: You misread me - I said that /dev/sda1 should be where your kernel etc stays, since it's your boot drive: "Move your kernel to /dev/**sda1**/3.8.13, move your initrd.img to /dev/sda1/initrd.img, move your grub directory to /dev/sda1/grub".

In grub, we're marking root=/dev/sda2, since that's what your root file system will be. You still have a /boot directory - /dev/sda1's file system provides the contents of that directory.

You have to remember that you have a split system - /boot is *not* on your root partition, and when you finally do boot, /boot will be served directly out of /dev/sda1.

Comment: I see at least one source of confusion, when I typed kernel /boot/3.8.13 I apparently had a symlink /boot -> / in my /dev/sda1 boot file system. For some reason I typed as if I were in my real (/dev/sda2) file system with /boot mounted there, but in fact I was just interacting with the /dev/sda1 file system. However, in short, I now have the kernel and initrd on / in /dev/sda1. I have modified the grub.conf as suggested by you and I still get just a prompt from grub. I have not run grub-install though, I'm given to understand that only lilo requires such updating.

Comment: Are you by chance using grub2? The configs changed completely between grub1 and grub2, and a lot of distros have been switching. I can't make heads or tails why it's doing this.

Comment: Sadly, my grub --version reads: GNU GRUB 0.97 (edit: yes, in my chrooted environment, i.e. the one I'm actually using when installing grub to my /dev/sda MBR)

Comment: Could it be related to how grub is installed? What exact command should I use to install grub?